# Getting same quality with "baseline profile"?

Tags: video, video-conversion, h.264

I have a couple of videos taken in H.264 using the high profile and I want to convert them into a baseline profile while keeping the same quality and size so, that they can be easily played on an older device without any lag issues.

So, somewhere I have read than High profile can achieve the same quality as baseline profile but it also reduces the file size. Is the opposite of this possible i.e. from high to baseline while keeping the same quality and doesn't matter the file size? Would I need the same bitrate?

Comment: related: [What are the differences between H.264 Profiles?](http://superuser.com/q/489087/172747)

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't say whether the opposite (from high to baseline) as I asked is true or not with same quality.

Comment: If going from base to high *with the same quality* results in a decrease in filesize then to go from high to base will require an increase in filesize *if you want the quality to be the same*. You will need to increase the bitrate for base to get the same quality as high. You don't get something for nothing.